# setAllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures not working in flutter webview

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, webview

I'm using the `webview_flutter plugin: ^4.2.0`
and

```
webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.4.2
```

And here's my problem, my iPhone swipe doesn't work at all to return to the previous page. Do not understand why? Maybe you have some ideas?

Here is my code

```
final _key = UniqueKey();
late final WebViewController webViewController;
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webViewController = WebViewController();
    if (webViewController is WebKitWebViewController) {
      (webViewController as WebKitWebViewController)
          .setAllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures(true);
    }
    webViewController
      ..enableZoom(false)
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));
  }

WebViewWidget(
                  controller: webViewController,
                  key: _key,
                )
```

Everything works on android

I just moved from version 3 to version 4+, in version three, I would do like this -

```
gestureNavigationEnabled: true
```

And that would work great.

Comment: Look into this solution: https://softans.com/question/setallowsbackforwardnavigationgestures-not-working-in-flutter-webview/#comment-503

Comment: @GHULAMNABI Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me. Swipe still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple, it was only necessary to add a platform

```
if (webViewController.platform is WebKitWebViewController) {
      (webViewController.platform as WebKitWebViewController)
          .setAllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures(true);
    }
```